# Overwriting object property (another object): should I delete the old one?

Tags: javascript

Say I do this:

```
const x = {
  nestedObject: {
     propertyOne: "nested obj1",
     propertyTwo: "zzz"
  }
};
```

And I want to eventually overwrite this x.nestedObject - is it better practice memory-wise to delete the old one first, or does it not matter? E.g:

```
delete x.nestedObject;

x.nestedObject = {
   propertyOne: "aaa",
   propertyTwo: "bbb"
};
```

Is the `delete x.nestedObject` line better practice or not?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Don't optimise prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference memory-wise.

If the nested object is not referenced elsewhere, it will become garbage as soon as the property is reassigned, and the garbage collector will reclaim the memory the next time it runs. The same thing happens if you delete the property.

Deleting a property or variable is only necessary if you're *not* going to reassign it and you need the memory used by its contents to be reclaimed. This is generally only important if the contents are large or you have many of them (e.g. a large array of objects).

If you're going to reassign the property later, it may be preferable to assign `null` to the property rather than delete it, so you can see the empty property as a placeholder when you're debugging.

Comment: "*Deleting a property or variable is only necessary if you're not going to reassign it soon*" I'd even say that you only need to delete properties if you don't need them present on the object. The object referenced by one can be made eligible for GC by doing `obj.prop = null`, assuming memory is a concern. It also serves as a marker that the property *should* normally be there.

Comment: @VLAZ  Deleting it has the added benefit that displaying the object won't show the unused property.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'd advise doing it if you don't need the property any more. If the property should normally be there but it's going to be reassigned later in the application, then marking it as `null` seems more appropriate. If you don't need that any more at all - it's not going to be reassigned or at least not definitely and not for a long time, then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter. If you are having the same properties in nestedObject, like property1, property2, then fine. If you are making different properties, you can always assign that property to null.

```
x.property1 = null;
x.newProperty = 'whatever'
```

That way, the garbage collector collects (although it really would only benefit if you are either using a lot of properties, or using this object a lot).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete anything as long as you are overwriting the same keys.

```js
const x = {
  nestedObject: {
     propertyOne: "nested obj1",
     propertyTwo: "zzz"
  }
};

console.log(x);

x.nestedObject = {
  propertyOne: "a",
  propertyTwo: "b"
}

console.log(x, 'after overwrite');
```